# Using require without export

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code (which works perfectly well) which I've borrowed from an online resource:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

require('./init/db');
require('./init/cache'); //Bring in Redis

//Define Routes
var userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

module.exports = app;
```

The bit I don't understand is "require" when used in this way? Here is the file it brings in:

```
//db.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = <theURI>;

mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// CONNECTION EVENTS
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
  console.log('Mongoose connected successfully');
});
```

It's the same with my Redis connection:

```
//cache.js
var redis  = require("redis");

var redisClient  = redis.createClient(process.env.CACHE_PORT, process.env.CACHE_URL);
redisClient.auth(process.env.CACHE_PASS);

redisClient.on("ready", function () {
  console.log("Cache is connected");
});
```

but as you can see there is no `module.exports` anywhere in the `db.js` or `cache.js` files! When I google this to understand how it works the examples always talk about `module.exports` and `require` together.

**Questions**

1. Could someone explain how require works when used on its own like this?
2. How can I make the cache/Redis connection available so that it can be used in my `userRoutes` file using something like: `var userRoutes = require('./routes/user')(redis);`

Comment: You can definitely export mongoose connection to use in other modules as a reference to DB. Just Google it(eg: export mongoose connection) and you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: My code is working fine and I can query the database from my routes file but I don't understand how!

Comment: Excellent question! Thank you for asking. It helped me understand a lot of things and get my work done!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> Could someone explain what is happening with this code? In other words, how does require work when not used with export.

We almost always see `require()` being used with `module.exports`, but you don't have to. When you don't export anything, the code in the imported module will still run, but you can't bind the import to a variable and interact with it.

Consider the following `Foo.js` module :

```
var foo = {};

foo.greet = function(){
    console.log('Hello from Foo!');
}

foo.greet();
```

I can import this module in my main file, like so :

```
require('./foo');
```

If I run this main file, the code inside the `Foo.js` module will run, and **Hello from Foo!** will be printed to the console.

However, I can't interact with the foo object directly. The following code will not work :

```
require('./foo');
foo.greet(); //ReferenceError, foo is not defined
```

I can bind the module import to a variable, but even this will not work :

```
var foo = require('./foo');
foo.greet(); //TypeError, foo.greet is not a function
```

To get it to work, I need to export the foo object from my module, using the `module.exports` that you are familiar with.

This demonstrates that you don't need to export anything from your modules, just like you don't need to bind the imported module to a variable when you are requiring it. The difference is that you won't be able to interact with the code in the imported module, if you don't export what you don't want to make visible in that module.

In the code in your question, importing Redis works because that module is self-contained, you don't need to interact with it in your code. You only need to import the code so that it can run (require the main Redis module and create the client)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Regarding the Redis part, I need to make the `redisClient` available in my `userRoutes` file. Is it a simple case of adding `module.exports = redisClient` at the bottom of the `cache.js` file?

Comment: Yes, if you export `redisClient` and bind the `require` to a variable then you will be able to access it via that variable

Comment: This is such a great answer! I was searching for something like this from a day after I got my 2 apps working from a single file. Great stuff! And superb question too!

Comment: So if I need an exports, I need to edit the module? Is this correct?

Comment: The variable inside that code can actually be accessed from outside if you don't 'use strict' and declare it globally. But of course I agree that is a terrible practice.

Answer (score 17):

Besides requiring a module that doesn't include exports to run it's side effects it's also possible for a module to define variables in the global scope which can be accessed in the file where the module is required. This happens by defining variables without the `var` keyword. It's not a good or common practice, but you might encounter it somewhere so it's good to know what is going on.

Example:

```
// foo.js
bar = 5;
```

And

```
// test.js
require('./foo');

console.log(bar);
// prints 5
```

If `bar`was defined as:

```
var bar = 5;
```

it would be in the module scope and not be accessible in `test.js`.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, I wanted to know what happens to variable defined as `var` when included from a module without export, they get automatically scoped and as such there is no problem with `var` assignments overrides. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When you call `require` the module is loaded and executed. So you have a connected mongoose. Actually `require` makes a function that your entire module code injected there and finally run.

Now, if you want to reuse variables created in modules you should export that. Like :

```
//cache.js
var redis  = require("redis");

var redisClient  = redis.createClient(process.env.CACHE_PORT, process.env.CACHE_URL);
redisClient.auth(process.env.CACHE_PASS);

redisClient.on("ready", function () {
  console.log("Cache is connected");
});

module.exports = redisClient;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added a comment for the other answer that is the same as this. Cheers anyway.