# How to import whole javascript file in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a .js file (JavaScript file) that no exports code. It have a constructor and some prototype methods. I need this to add in the ReactJS App.

What I tried is, adding a script tag in client/index.html. Then upload the js file to client folder. When I call the constructor in my Apps.jsx file, I received an error, Constructor_name not defined.

How can I do it in correct way?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information

Comment: What other information you need? By the way, I can't do import from 'file.js'; because as I said, there are no exports code. (export const file = function(){...};)

Comment: In short, you can't. You can import a function for side effects, but you can't import and use a file's contents unless it's exporting something. Check this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172337/using-require-without-export

Comment: If I can't, how can I call the constructor in that file? and its methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this in our project. You have to use a common object that both the browser and React share. So just create a reference into the window object.

```
import Foo from 'Foo';
import App from 'App';

//Foo.js
class Foo { constructor() {} }
window.Foo = Foo;

//App.jsx
let foo = new window.Foo();
```

If you have several you want to access and don't want to pollute the global scope:

```
//Foo.js
class Foo { constructor() {} }
window.MyApp = { Foo: Foo };
```